# Django view - exclude in queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have a problem:
After creating new world, (all countries are automatically assigned to every new world) user choose one country which will showed on top of the site and he can't delete this country. How to do this?

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of country", max_length=100, default="Australia")
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="number of country", default="1")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class World(models.Model):
    country = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="New Map", max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now i have this: after creating world user is redirecting to new_my_world, there he should choose his country and be redirected to site with my_world view where he can delete countires expect this one. How to do this?
views.py

```
def new_my_world(request, pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'game/new_my_world.html', {'world': world})

def my_world(request, pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World.objects.exclude(??, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world})

def choose_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=pk)
    return redirect('my_world', pk=world.pk)
```

I know in my_world view there's should be something with exclude (excluding this coosen country) but i don't know how to connect it.

edit

url:

```
  url(r'^world/(?P<pk>[%&+ \w]+)/(?P<country_pk>[%&+ \w]+)/$', views.my_world, name='my_world'),
```

edit2:

How create url to my_world? After creating new world,when i click on first country to choose it i get an error

with this url:

```
url(r'^world/(?P<pk>[%&+ \w]+)/(?P<country_pk>[%&+ \w]+)/$', views.my_world, name='my_world'),

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/world/22/9/
Raised by:  game.views.my_world

No World matches the given query.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix choose_country to the following:

```
def choose_country(request, world_pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=world_pk)
    country = get_object_or_404(Country, pk=country_pk)
    return redirect('my_world', pk=world.pk, country_pk = country.id)
```

Then in your my_world function it should be changed like this:

```
def my_world(request, pk, country_pk):
    world = get_object_or_404(World.objects.exclude(country__id = country_pk), pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world})
```

**Edit 1**
if the country is the same of as the country of my world, the above `get_object_or_404(World.objects.exclude(country__id = country_pk), pk=pk)` will for sure return Not Found. So I suggest that my_world to be as follows:

```
def my_world(request, pk, country_pk):
        world = get_object_or_404(World, pk=pk)
        countries = get_object_or_404(Country.object.exclude(pk=country_pk))
        return render(request, 'game/my_world.html', {'world': world, 'countries': countries})
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good but now after that i have a problem with invalid syntax: it says is about view my_world

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Missing a close paren on the first line of `my_world`.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe you know how to repair this problem? my_world() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) It is probably something about country_pk

Comment: Yes it is, you should pass both ids to my_world through urls

Comment: Thank you for your patience, i repaired it, I pasted in main post this line with url. After that i get error: MultipleObjectsReturned at /world/20/5/. get() returned more than one World -- it returned 30!

Comment: This is because that world returned is not a single one but multiple objects. so I've edited `world = get_object_or_404(World.objects.exclude(country__id = country_pk), pk=pk)`. It either return a world which is not one of the country or it returns not found

Comment: Ok, now i understand but how to include this primary keys in my url? I edited my first post, i tried to change url to my_world but i get an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102529/discussion-between-ahmed-hosny-and-znawca).